# JavaEE Tutorial Not Working - Lost In A Sea of Exceptions

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jms

I am trying to execute the simple JMS Java EE example at the following URL: https://javaee.github.io/tutorial/jms-examples003.html#GKTJS I was doing alright until this section: https://javaee.github.io/tutorial/jms-examples003.html#to-run-the-producer-client

The code being executed when the problems happen is as follows:

```
/**
 * Copyright (c) 2014 Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.
 *
 * You may not modify, use, reproduce, or distribute this software except in
 * compliance with  the terms of the License at:
 * https://github.com/javaee/tutorial-examples/LICENSE.txt
 */
package javaeetutorial.producer;

import javax.annotation.Resource;
import javax.jms.ConnectionFactory;
import javax.jms.Destination;
import javax.jms.JMSContext;
import javax.jms.JMSRuntimeException;
import javax.jms.Queue;
import javax.jms.Topic;

/**
 * The Producer class consists only of a main method, which sends several
 * messages to a queue or topic.
 *
 * Run this program in conjunction with SynchConsumer or AsynchConsumer. Specify
 * "queue" or "topic" on the command line when you run the program. By default,
 * the program sends one message. Specify a number after the destination name to
 * send that number of messages.
 */
public class Producer {

    @Resource(lookup = "java:comp/DefaultJMSConnectionFactory")
    private static ConnectionFactory connectionFactory;
    @Resource(lookup = "jms/MyQueue")
    private static Queue queue;
    @Resource(lookup = "jms/MyTopic")
    private static Topic topic;

    /**
     * Main method.
     *
     * @param args the destination used by the example and, optionally, the
     * number of messages to send
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final int NUM_MSGS;

        if ((args.length < 1) || (args.length > 2)) {
            System.err.println(
                    "Program takes one or two arguments: "
                    + "<dest_type> [<number-of-messages>]");
            System.exit(1);
        }

        String destType = args[0];
        System.out.println("Destination type is " + destType);

        if (!(destType.equals("queue") || destType.equals("topic"))) {
            System.err.println("Argument must be \"queue\" or " + "\"topic\"");
            System.exit(1);
        }

        if (args.length == 2) {
            NUM_MSGS = (new Integer(args[1])).intValue();
        } else {
            NUM_MSGS = 1;
        }

        Destination dest = null;

        try {
            if (destType.equals("queue")) {
                dest = (Destination) queue;
            } else {
                dest = (Destination) topic;
            }
        } catch (JMSRuntimeException e) {
            System.err.println("Error setting destination: " + e.toString());
            System.exit(1);
        }

        /*
         * Within a try-with-resources block, create context.
         * Create producer and message.
         * Send messages, varying text slightly.
         * Send end-of-messages message.
         */
        try (JMSContext context = connectionFactory.createContext();) {
            int count = 0;

            for (int i = 0; i < NUM_MSGS; i++) {
                String message = "This is message " + (i + 1) 
                        + " from producer";
                // Comment out the following line to send many messages
                System.out.println("Sending message: " + message);
                context.createProducer().send(dest, message);
                count += 1;
            }
            System.out.println("Text messages sent: " + count);

            /*
             * Send a non-text control message indicating end of
             * messages.
             */
            context.createProducer().send(dest, context.createMessage());
            // Uncomment the following line if you are sending many messages
            // to two synchronous consumers
            // context.createProducer().send(dest, context.createMessage());
        } catch (JMSRuntimeException e) {
            System.err.println("Exception occurred: " + e.toString());
            System.exit(1);
        }
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

There is also a glassfish-resources.xml file with the following code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE resources PUBLIC "-//GlassFish.org//DTD GlassFish Application Server 3.1 Resource Definitions//EN" "http://glassfish.org/dtds/glassfish-resources_1_5.dtd">
<resources>
  <admin-object-resource enabled="true" jndi-name="jms/MyQueue" object-type="user" res-adapter="jmsra" res-type="javax.jms.Queue">
    <description/>
    <property name="Name" value="PhysicalQueue"/>
  </admin-object-resource>
  <admin-object-resource enabled="true" jndi-name="jms/MyTopic" object-type="user" res-adapter="jmsra" res-type="javax.jms.Topic">
    <description/>
    <property name="Name" value="PhysicalTopic"/>
  </admin-object-resource>
</resources>
```

This XML file is used as follows:

```
asadmin add-resources src/main/setup/glassfish-resources.xml
```

This command creates the queue and topic destinations. I can view them in the GlassFish admin console. Please see a screenshot of this below as follows: 
[image]

The program is run as follows:

```
appclient -client target/producer.jar queue 3
```

At this point I received all of these errors:

```
C:\glassfish5\java_ee_sdk-8\glassfish5\docs\javaee-tutorial\examples\jms\simple\
producer>appclient -client target/producer.jar queue 3

org.omg.CORBA.COMM_FAILURE: FINE: 00410008: Connection abort  vmcid: OMG  minor
code: 8 completed: Maybe
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy38.connectionAbort(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.transport.ConnectionImpl.doOptimizedReadStrateg
y(ConnectionImpl.java:1287)
        at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.transport.ConnectionImpl.doWork(ConnectionImpl.
java:845)
        at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.threadpool.ThreadPoolImpl$WorkerThread.performW
ork(ThreadPoolImpl.java:497)
        at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.threadpool.ThreadPoolImpl$WorkerThread.run(Thre
adPoolImpl.java:540)
Caused by: org.omg.CORBA.COMM_FAILURE: FINE: 00410011: IOException received when
 reading from connection SocketOrChannelConnectionImpl[ java.nio.channels.Socket
Channel[connected local=/127.0.0.1:12255 remote=localhost/127.0.0.1:3700] ESTABL
ISHED true true]  vmcid: OMG  minor code: 11  completed: No
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy38.ioexceptionWhenReadingConnection(Unknown Sourc
e)
        at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.transport.ConnectionImpl.nonBlockingRead(Connec
tionImpl.java:1465)
        at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.transport.ConnectionImpl.doOptimizedReadStrateg
y(ConnectionImpl.java:1241)
        ... 3 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: End-of-stream
        at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.transport.ConnectionImpl.nonBlockingRead(Connec
tionImpl.java:1458)
        ... 4 more
com.sun.enterprise.container.common.spi.util.InjectionException: Exception attem
pting to inject Res-Ref-Env-Property: javaeetutorial.producer.Producer/connectio
nFactory@javax.jms.ConnectionFactory@ resolved as: jndi: java:comp/DefaultJMSCon
nectionFactory@res principal: null@mail: null
No Runtime properties
Database Vendor : null
Create Tables at Deploy : false
Delete Tables at Undeploy : false into class javaeetutorial.producer.Producer: L
ookup failed for 'java:comp/env/javaeetutorial.producer.Producer/connectionFacto
ry' in SerialContext[myEnv={java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterprise.namin
g.impl.SerialInitContextFactory, java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise
.naming, java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDISt
ateFactoryImpl}
        at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.util.InjectionManagerImpl._i
nject(InjectionManagerImpl.java:740)
        at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.util.InjectionManagerImpl.in
ject(InjectionManagerImpl.java:507)
        at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.util.InjectionManagerImpl.in
jectClass(InjectionManagerImpl.java:235)
        at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.util.InjectionManagerImpl.in
jectClass(InjectionManagerImpl.java:227)
        at org.glassfish.appclient.client.acc.AppClientContainer$ClientMainClass
Setting.getClientMainClass(AppClientContainer.java:636)
        at org.glassfish.appclient.client.acc.AppClientContainer.getMainMethod(A
ppClientContainer.java:525)
        at org.glassfish.appclient.client.acc.AppClientContainer.completePrepara
tion(AppClientContainer.java:419)
        at org.glassfish.appclient.client.acc.AppClientContainer.prepare(AppClie
ntContainer.java:320)
        at org.glassfish.appclient.client.AppClientFacade.prepareACC(AppClientFa
cade.java:283)
        at org.glassfish.appclient.client.acc.agent.AppClientContainerAgent.prem
ain(AppClientContainerAgent.java:83)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.
java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAcces
sorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
        at sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.loadClassAndStartAgent(Instrumenta
tionImpl.java:386)
        at sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.loadClassAndCallPremain(Instrument
ationImpl.java:401)
Caused by: javax.naming.NamingException: Lookup failed for 'java:comp/env/javaee
tutorial.producer.Producer/connectionFactory' in SerialContext[myEnv={java.namin
g.factory.initial=com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialInitContextFactory, java.
naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.naming, java.naming.factory.state=com
.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl} [Root exception is jav
ax.naming.NamingException: Lookup failed for 'java:comp/DefaultJMSConnectionFact
ory' in SerialContext[myEnv={java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterprise.nami
ng.impl.SerialInitContextFactory, java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterpris
e.naming, java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIS
tateFactoryImpl, com.sun.enterprise.naming.logicalName=java:comp/env/javaeetutor
ial.producer.Producer/connectionFactory} [Root exception is javax.naming.NamingE
xception: Lookup failed for 'jms/__defaultConnectionFactory' in SerialContext[my
Env={java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialInitContex
tFactory, java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.naming, java.naming.fa
ctory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl} [Root e
xception is javax.naming.NamingException: Unable to acquire SerialContextProvide
r for SerialContext[myEnv={java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterprise.naming
.impl.SerialInitContextFactory, java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.
naming, java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDISta
teFactoryImpl} [Root exception is org.omg.CORBA.COMM_FAILURE: FINE: 00410008: Co
nnection abort  vmcid: OMG  minor code: 8 completed: Maybe]]]]
        at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.jav
a:491)
        at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.jav
a:438)
        at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:417)
        at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.util.InjectionManagerImpl._i
nject(InjectionManagerImpl.java:638)
        ... 15 more
Caused by: javax.naming.NamingException: Lookup failed for 'java:comp/DefaultJMS
ConnectionFactory' in SerialContext[myEnv={java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.e
nterprise.naming.impl.SerialInitContextFactory, java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com
.sun.enterprise.naming, java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presenta
tion.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl, com.sun.enterprise.naming.logicalName=java:comp/e
nv/javaeetutorial.producer.Producer/connectionFactory} [Root exception is javax.
naming.NamingException: Lookup failed for 'jms/__defaultConnectionFactory' in Se
rialContext[myEnv={java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.Se
rialInitContextFactory, java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.naming,
java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactor
yImpl} [Root exception is javax.naming.NamingException: Unable to acquire Serial
ContextProvider for SerialContext[myEnv={java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.ent
erprise.naming.impl.SerialInitContextFactory, java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.s
un.enterprise.naming, java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentati
on.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl} [Root exception is org.omg.CORBA.COMM_FAILURE: FINE
: 00410008: Connection abort  vmcid: OMG  minor code: 8 completed: Maybe]]]
        at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.jav
a:491)
        at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.jav
a:438)
        at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:417)
        at com.sun.enterprise.naming.util.JndiNamingObjectFactory.create(JndiNam
ingObjectFactory.java:90)
        at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.GlassfishNamingManagerImpl.lookup(Glas
sfishNamingManagerImpl.java:745)
        at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.GlassfishNamingManagerImpl.lookup(Glas
sfishNamingManagerImpl.java:715)
        at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.JavaURLContext.lookup(JavaURLContext.j
ava:159)
        at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.jav
a:471)
        ... 18 more
Caused by: javax.naming.NamingException: Lookup failed for 'jms/__defaultConnect
ionFactory' in SerialContext[myEnv={java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterpri
se.naming.impl.SerialInitContextFactory, java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.en
terprise.naming, java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rm
i.JNDIStateFactoryImpl} [Root exception is javax.naming.NamingException: Unable
to acquire SerialContextProvider for SerialContext[myEnv={java.naming.factory.in
itial=com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialInitContextFactory, java.naming.facto
ry.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.naming, java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.e
e.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl} [Root exception is org.omg.CORBA.C
OMM_FAILURE: FINE: 00410008: Connection abort  vmcid: OMG  minor code: 8 complet
ed: Maybe]]
        at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.jav
a:491)
        at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.jav
a:438)
        at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:417)
        at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.jms.system.DefaultJMSConnectionFactory.
handle(DefaultJMSConnectionFactory.java:84)
        at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.NamedNamingObjectManager.tryNamedProxi
es(NamedNamingObjectManager.java:135)
        at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.JavaURLContext.lookup(JavaURLContext.j
ava:164)
        at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.jav
a:471)
        ... 25 more
Caused by: javax.naming.NamingException: Unable to acquire SerialContextProvider
 for SerialContext[myEnv={java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterprise.naming.
impl.SerialInitContextFactory, java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.n
aming, java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStat
eFactoryImpl} [Root exception is org.omg.CORBA.COMM_FAILURE: FINE: 00410008: Con
nection abort  vmcid: OMG  minor code: 8 completed: Maybe]
        at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.getProvider(SerialContex
t.java:334)
        at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.jav
a:477)
        ... 31 more
Caused by: org.omg.CORBA.COMM_FAILURE: FINE: 00410008: Connection abort  vmcid:
OMG  minor code: 8 completed: Maybe
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy38.connectionAbort(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.transport.ConnectionImpl.doOptimizedReadStrateg
y(ConnectionImpl.java:1287)
        at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.transport.ConnectionImpl.doWork(ConnectionImpl.
java:845)
        at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.threadpool.ThreadPoolImpl$WorkerThread.performW
ork(ThreadPoolImpl.java:497)
        at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.threadpool.ThreadPoolImpl$WorkerThread.run(Thre
adPoolImpl.java:540)
Caused by: org.omg.CORBA.COMM_FAILURE: FINE: 00410011: IOException received when
 reading from connection SocketOrChannelConnectionImpl[ java.nio.channels.Socket
Channel[connected local=/127.0.0.1:12255 remote=localhost/127.0.0.1:3700] ESTABL
ISHED true true]  vmcid: OMG  minor code: 11  completed: No
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy38.ioexceptionWhenReadingConnection(Unknown Sourc
e)
        at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.transport.ConnectionImpl.nonBlockingRead(Connec
tionImpl.java:1465)
        at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.transport.ConnectionImpl.doOptimizedReadStrateg
y(ConnectionImpl.java:1241)
        ... 3 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: End-of-stream
        at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.transport.ConnectionImpl.nonBlockingRead(Connec
tionImpl.java:1458)
        ... 4 more

C:\glassfish5\java_ee_sdk-8\glassfish5\docs\javaee-tutorial\examples\jms\simple\
producer>
```

I know that the Glassfish server is running because I can log into the administration console. I noticed part of the exception error message mentions database. This part of the message is as follows, "com.sun.enterprise.container.common.spi.util.InjectionException: Exception attempting to inject Res-Ref-Env-Property: javaeetutorial.producer.Producer/connectionFactory@javax.jms.ConnectionFactory@ resolved as: jndi: java:comp/DefaultJMSCon
nectionFactory@res principal: null@mail: null
No Runtime properties
Database Vendor : null
Create Tables at Deploy : false
Delete Tables at Undeploy"

I tried to start the database, Derby, that is in the Glassfish server but received an error. I think this has something to so with the port number. I need to start the database on a specific port number... Maybe... 0_O

Does anyone know what is going wrong? I am trying to learn JMS, Java EE stuff. I am just following the directions. I have no idea what is going wrong. I think the main problem is these types of exceptions:

```
com.sun.enterprise.container.common.spi.util.InjectionException: Exception attempting to inject Res-Ref-Env-Property: javaeetutorial.producer.Producer/connectionFactory@javax.jms.ConnectionFactory@ resolved as: jndi: java:comp/DefaultJMSConnectionFactory@res principal: null@mail: null
```

I have a feeling I will never know the answer to this. :0

***UPDATE - The example works (for me) now***

Well I do not know what was causing the problem but I was able to get the example to run. What I did was go through the example again and `mvn clean install` to re-build the Producer.java program. There are a lot of "moving parts" in this type of Java EE application. I have no idea what was going wrong. 0_o The screenshot below shows that the example runs without all the previous errors and as shown in the webpage at the top of this post. 
[image]

Comment: Could you post some of your code? It would be easier to help.

Comment: I agree on the code.  You also have a number of these `NamingException: Lookup failed for ` did you have a task of setting up a couple queues on the GlassFish app server manually or is the producer and or consumer supposed to be dynamically creating the queues?  Possibly the queues aren't being created because of the database error (they could be reliant on the database for durability of messages) so corrected the database issue would be a good start.  Update your question with both code examples and the database error/exception.

Comment: Hi guise, I will post my code! I have a feeling this is not actually a database issue though as the example does not mention having to start Derby, the name of the database the currently ships with Glassfish.